# Field mapping from json response to custom object

Tags: apex

I am getting fields like fullname,personalphone,personalfax from an external webservice , the result is in json response which holds all the fields above. Fullname field in json response is like this "Michael$stone" so there is a delimiter. My requirement is to map these fields to lead object i.e
firstname=michael , lastname=stone and  phone=personalphone.  field names are different in json and they cannot be mapped directly to salesforce Lead object fields. Here's where I require help. Can anyone provide a proper solution to map those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider writing a class to deserialize into. You can add an instance method to it that does additional parsing.

```
public class LeadResponse
{
    public final String fullName, personalPhone; // etc.
    public Lead getRecord()
    {
        String firstName, lastName;
        if (fulllName != null)
        {
            firstName = fullName.substringBefore('$');
            lastName = fullName.substringAfter('$');
        }
        return new Lead(
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            Phone = personalPhone
            // etc.
        );
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to do something like:

```
JSON payload; // get from webservice
LeadResponse response = (LeadResponse)JSON.deserialize(payload, LeadResponse.class);
Lead record = response.getRecord();
```

If you get a response with many `Lead` records, your deserialization process would change, but the class would stay the same:

```
JSON payload; // get from webservice
List<LeadResponse> responses = (List<LeadResponse>)
    JSON.deserialize(payload, List<LeadResponse>.class);

List<Lead> records = new List<Lead>();
for (LeadResponse response : responses)
    records.add(response.getRecord());
```

Comment: Another great approach. Just a concern If there are 100 fields , then it would be writing 100 lines of code for mapping. and Here if json field name changes then again redeploy code.

Comment: Notice how you can combine multiple fields per line. Logical lines, sure, you need one per. Anyway hopefully the webservice isn's so volatile that this class would require changes all the time. It's just one approach that I have found works well.

Comment: Agreed.  For a stable webservices it's a better choice.

Comment: @adrian, I liked ur code.should it be  public List<String> firstname {get;set;} because in json string we will have many records?

Comment: @Krishna No, in that case you would deserialize into a `List<LeadResponse>` (see updated answer).

Comment: @adrian,I am extending this concept.assume in json fullname=michaelstone, then should I create a wrapper class, say Lead field Name=fullname, cud u pls elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Well I too had a similar requirement. 
So I solved it by creating a List custom setting having 2 columns.

Json field Name and FieldAPIName.

Some Sample Data for the List custom setting will look like.

phone=personalphone

fullName=Custom

Date=closeDate

age=age__C

Stage=StageName__C

We have Sobject [**put**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method that can help you dynamically set values of fields on runtime. So even if JSON field changes or Lead's field Name changes ,you just have to update custom setting's value.

so your code will look similar like.

```
public Lead parseLeadJson(String responseJSON){
  Map<String,String> leadFieldMap= (Map<String,String>)JSON.serializeUntyped(responseJSON);
  Lead newLead=new Lead();
  for(String jsonFieldName:leadFieldMap.keySet()){

   String leadFieldName=LeadMappingCustomSetting__C.getValue(jsonFieldName).FieldAPIName__C;   
   if(leadFieldMap.get(jsonFieldName)!='Custom')
       newLead.put(leadFieldName,leadFieldMap.get(jsonFieldName));
   else{
      //String fname; Use split and handle it
     }

    }
return newlead;
}
```

Ofc few strange cases like Michael$stone fullname has to be handeled by if else clause, but thats the most simpler structure i can come up with.

Comment: didnt understand ur code. In CS, Json fieldname=Name & apiname=fulname, so how it store? also json data very huge so can all json field name be mapped to lead field name?

Comment: List custom settings are like Custom objects that can store multiple values.
Updated code for clarifications.

Comment: Hi cud I mail you(personal ID) and have a chat?

Comment: Its on my profile. U can have a look.

Comment: Hi I mailed u. cud u pls chk.

Answer (score -1):

I do something similar to this in a managed package though I store all the JSON to Contact field mappings in Custom MetaData.

The JSON I get from the webservice has a list of records, so to process them, I deserialize the list, and then for each record, I loop through my custom metadata table of field mappings and create a contact based on the mappings. I then insert the list. 
To handle different field types, I also store that info in the custom metadata table so I can cast the types correctly, and handle things like Multi Value Lists and Dates correctly.